# Data for the distribution of US household annual income by year and state

Tags: data-request

I am looking for data regarding the annual household income distribution filtered by year and state (and finer geographical feature like cities). In other words, I am looking for data with the following features (label being the number of earners):

- year
- state
- income range (e.g. 10K-20K, finer better)

Does anyone know if there is a publicly available dataset containing these?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the US census bureau? Income related website [here](http://www.census.gov/hhes/www/income/).

Furthermore there is a kaggle training competition about the census data. Have a look [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/2013-american-community-survey/data) for the available data tables. Data straight from the census bureau.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out the following free, open databases on Quandl which show historical mean or median household incomes by state:

Federal Reserve Economic Data - https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED

National Center for Education Statistics - https://www.quandl.com/data/NCES

Hope this helps! [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]